# Transfer data async from one program to another

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, basic

I am running a python program on a Raspberry Pi. This program writes data to a txt-file every second (every second some data is changed).

On a laptop I am running a Studio Basic program that reads that data file over the network from the Raspberry. This works OK as long as the time between the reads from that that file are more than 15 seconds apart. If I read/access faster than the same data is read. It looks that the windows program reads from a cache if it is accessed in less than 15 seconds. Is there a way to change the time limit so I can read more often (let us say every 5 seconds).

Note if I read the txt-data file using another python program in the Raspberry Pi than the changed data is read OK by that program. So the problem lies in the Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [File Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-caching) document, use `win32file.CreateFile` and specify `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to disable the cache, all read and write operations will directly access the physical disk.

EDIT :

For using `CreateFile` in VB.net, please refer to:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a2ebfaa-d56d-487a-b03d-0f9ca72e3bbc/createfile-and-deviceiocontrol-function-in-vbnet?forum=winembplatdev